# Не могу запустить приложение - ошибка "run-as: exec failed for lib/gdbserver: No such file or directory"

Tags: android, delphi

Не могу запустить приложение написанное на Delphi XE 10.3, на своем Android устройстве Honor Play, а так же на любом другом виртуальном устройстве под Android. Получаю вот такую ошибку:

[image: run-as: exec failed for lib/gdbserver: No such file or directory]

Если нажать кнопку подробней:

[image: Подробней по ошибке]

Вот callstack на локальной машине:

[image: callstack]

Сам проект по ходу копируется на устройство, на него так же создаётся иконка, но если запускать это приложение по нажатию на иконку, то вылетает ошибка....

[image: Приложение на Andoid-е]

Вот настройки пути SDK:

[image: SDK]

Настройки пути NDK:

[image: NDK]

Настройки пути JAVA:

[image: JAVA]